# Regular expression remove special characters after domain in email

Tags: regex, validation, email-validation

I facing one challenge that needs experts' advice. I found one expression which is validating email correctly but still not able to find/remove special characters.

> for example xxxx.xxx@domain.com#

if you can notice there is # at the end of email, how can I remove that what expression I am using is this.

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Comment: Hint: remove hashes at the end of strings with `#+$` regular expression.

Comment: What tool/language are you using?

Comment: I got it from one blog Am really sorry I lost the link of that blog.